# Restrict Keyboard Input jQuery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

How would you go about Restricting Keyboard Input on a textbox using Jquery?

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean restrict it? Limit it to certain letters? Or stop any text from being entered?

Comment: Well I have a jQuery Datepicker textbox and it allows you to specify what date format you want, unfortunately it allows 33/335233/30010 when it should only allow mm/dd/yyyy so to make sure that the user doesn't put in any invalid input I am restricting input from the keyboard so the user can only select dates via the datepicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the user to be able to type anything in the text-box, then consider the `readonly` and `disabled` attributes. If the data in the textbox is needed at the server side, make it `readonly`. If not, make it `disabled`.

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />

<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

If you want the user to be able to type in something, but only restrict certain types of characters such as numbers only, then listen to the `keyup` event on the textbox. It is fired whenever a key is released inside the text box. On this events callback, check the value of the textbox, and make changes to the value as necessary.

Comment: +1 Given the comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543029/restrict-keyboard-input-jquery#comment-2543967), it seems `readonly` is the way to go (it allows focus, but no input).

Answer (score 0):

for `<input type="text">` use attribute `maxlength`